# How to improve the performance of my Recyclerview holding images retrieved from Firebase? (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, android-recyclerview

This might look like a generalized duplicate question but actually, I want to know about any chances of improvement in this piece of code as from what I have known from others is that the code in the "*onBindViewHolder()*" should be efficient enough to not slow down the RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.getLayoutParams().width = (widthPixels / 2) - 28;

    StorageReference sr = images.get(position);
    GlideApp.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
            .load(sr)
            .thumbnail(0.2f)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.background_splash)
            .into(holder.album);
    holder.albumTitle.setText(giveName(sr.getName()));

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.itemView, "Wall" + (position + 1) + "_Transition");
}
```

Currently, I don't have many images to access from the Firebase but suppose the number turns to something like **500**, will this part of the code do any harm in the **long run**?

(I also got to know about something called "DiffUtil" but don't want to experiment on something new right now.)

(Full code of my app if that's important: https://github.com/Sujal1245/WALLisWALL-Wallpaper-App)

Comment: I think the way you are doing it is right. I dont think it can be improved as the image is going to take some time to load because its being loaded from the network and not from the local storage.

Comment: Are you willing to request all those 500 images at once? Where are the image URLs stored? In Firestore or the in the Realtime Database?

Comment: Not URLs actually. All images will be in Firebase Storage.

Comment: I know loading all of them at once won't be wise but just in case I do, will this much code affect the performance badly?

Comment: My app on Play Store using this rn: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Sujal_Industries.wallpapers.WALLisWALL

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry for tagging so late but I completely forgot about doing this while replying that day.

Comment: Yes, it's not a good approach to request all those 500 images at once.

Comment: @AlexMamo What's the way you would personally recommend? :)

Comment: I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, I don't have many images to access from the Firebase but suppose the number turns to something like 500, will this part of the code do any harm in the long run?

It's not about a particular part of your code as it's about the amount of data you download. It's not a recommended approach to request all those 500 images at once. Besides that, I don't think that somebody will be interested in seeing all those images. Not to mention that will take a large amount of time. So the best option that you have is to limit the number of images you read.

How can you achieve that? Simply by storing the URL of each image, either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), and read them in smaller chunks. A common approach would be to always display the exact number of images that you are able to display on the screen. That being said, you should consider getting data progressively. You can also consider implementing [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) if your app's use case requires it.

> I also got to know about something called "DiffUtil" but don't want to experiment on something new right now.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil):

> DiffUtil is a utility class that calculates the difference between two lists and outputs a list of update operations that converts the first list into the second one.

So if you still consider downloading all those 500 images in one go, DiffUtil won't save bandwidth for you.

Comment: Thank you. That day I completely forgot about accepting the answer. I am not sure if it's the right place to ask but could you help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71094174/9520315 ?

Comment: @SujalKumar I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.