# FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-installations-executor-2 (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

This crash is **only** happening when the app is downloaded from the Play Store. The activity opens up and stays fine for a few seconds but just after that.. this is happening:

```
2022-02-12 22:32:50.927 6188-6283/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-installations-executor-2
Process: com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes, PID: 6188
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:220)
    at l6.c.g(SourceFile:346)
    at l6.b.run(SourceFile:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I tried reproducing the crash in debug mode(by enabling proguard) but couldn't so I think it has nothing to do with proguard optimizations/exclusions.

Here's the code from **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SelfNotes";
    private static final String spFileKey = "SelfNotes.SECRET_FILE";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    Button button;

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
            this::onSignInResult
    );


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        doInitialSetup();
    }

    private void doInitialSetup() {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(spFileKey, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FCM", false)) {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Global")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                            editor.putBoolean("FCM", true);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
                                editor.putBoolean("FCM", false);
                            }
                            editor.apply();
                            Log.d(TAG, msg);
                        });
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), App.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Choose authentication providers
            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

            // Create and launch sign-in intent
            Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build();
            signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FCM", false)) {
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Global")
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                                editor.putBoolean("FCM", true);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
                                    editor.putBoolean("FCM", false);
                                }
                                editor.apply();
                                Log.d(TAG, msg);
                            });
                }
                // Accessing Cloud FireStore...
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                //Creating New User...
                String name = user.getDisplayName();
                String email = user.getEmail();
                if (email != null && name != null) {
                    Map<String, Object> newUser = new HashMap<>();
                    newUser.put("Name", name);
                    db.collection("users")
                            .document(email)
                            .set(newUser);
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), App.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                // ...
                Log.e(TAG, "Failure!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.4.7"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.1.0-rc1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/android_alarmmanager"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/android_alarmmanager"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Add"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".App"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/android_alarmmanager" />
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="FirebaseChannel" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="notes.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="3" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Full Code here: https://github.com/Sujal1245/SelfNotes

App's link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Sujal_Industries.Notes.SelfNotes

I have searched for similar errors but couldn't find one like my case. The logcat too is a bit confusing to me.

**UPDATE**:

I **removed** the **Firebase Analytics** library and now **no crashes** but I still would like to know the exact reason behind the crash.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

I have some problem here. When running in debug mode, it just looks fine. But when run in release mode, I got the same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did it start after using Firebase Analytics too?